# AWS client error - Unable to launch workspace session

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have been using my amazon workspace account without any issues, after an update I started getting an error,"Unable to connect - We cannot launch your session. Contact system administrator.". I was able to RDP to my workspace. My IT support deleted my workspace and rebuilt the workspace, I still had the same issue. They duplicated my AD account with new user name and password, with this new account I could launch my workspace client and I also could RDP. So my AD account was not the problem. Looking into the log file saw the following error :

2021-02-20T02:23:06.575Z { Version: "3.1.3.1649" }: [DBG] Provision Session Response Received
2021-02-20T02:23:06.604Z { Version: "3.1.3.1649" }: [ERR] Connection to target failed. SNI:
2021-02-20T02:23:06.604Z { Version: "3.1.3.1649" }: [ERR] Error while calling SessionProvision: PcoipSessionProvisionUnknownError

Apart from this, there were no other errors.

Answer (score 0):

With Amazons help finally after a week the issue was resolved. The reason being special characters in the password > and <. This bug exists only for Amazon Workspace Client, not with RDP. Special character @, ! is fine but with some other character you will experience this issue. The solution was to change the password with only special character mentioned earlier.